# Haml error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ...:Util.html_safe(_erbout);ensure;@haml_buffer = @haml_buffer.... ... ^

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am getting error like this:
[image]

Actually i am using 2 spaces haml syntax too. With haml tag it works, with ruby code not. How to fix it guys?

Here is code:

```
    %li
      = image_tag('leaf.jpg')
        .caption
          .slide-text-info.bounceInDown{"data-wow-delay" => "0.4s"}
            %h1 welcome to our marketplace
            %p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Sed nisi metus,tristique ndolor non,ornare sagittis dolor.Nulla vestibulu lacus...
            .slide-btns
              %a.startnow{:href => "#"} VIWE MORE
              %a.livedemo{:href => "#"} VIDEO TOUR
```

Comment: The screenshot is hard to look. Please share the code.

Comment: try replacing `-` with `=`

Comment: yeah i know and in the code i did this but still same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put content inside a block:

```
%li
  = image_tag('leaf.jpg') do
    .caption
      .slide-text-info.bounceInDown{"data-wow-delay" => "0.4s"}
        %h1 welcome to our marketplace
        %p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Sed nisi metus,tristique ndolor non,ornare sagittis dolor.Nulla vestibulu lacus...
        .slide-btns

          %a.startnow{:href => "#"} VIWE MORE
          %a.livedemo{:href => "#"} VIDEO TOUR
```

(Note the `do` after `image_tag`)